# How to merge .rpmnew files in Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM)?

Tags: rpm, pam, upgrade

A few `.rpmnew` files are being created after performing an upgrade of the Fedora OS. The normal procedure for merging `.rpmnew` files into the original ones is to compare the differences, make the necessary changes to the configuration on the `.rpmnew` files, and replace the original files with the new ones. However, the files contained in `/etc/pam.d` are **links** to files with same the filename appended with `-ac`, example:

`password-auth` links to `password-auth-ac` and has `password-auth.rpmnew` as upgrade.

How do I go about merging these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in RPM that is supposed to detect file differences fails on this edge case, where the destination has been made into a symlink. In the case of these particular files, they are generally safe to replace with the new versions that came in the new RPMs.

```
mv /etc/pam.d/password-auth.rpmnew /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac
```

Comment: I see, so I just need to replace those `-ac` files and not the links.